# How can I decompose an image into 8 x 8 pixel blocks?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

```
 I=imread('X.jpg'); 
 [a b]=size(I);
 figure;imshow(I);
j=rgb2ycbcr(I);
figure;
imshow(j);
ca=mat2cell(j,8*ones(1,size(j,1)/8),8*ones(1,size(j,2)/8),3);
p=1; 

 for c=1:size(ca,1)
  for r=1:size(ca,2)
    subplot(8,8,p);
    imshow(ca{c,r});
    p=p+1;
    end
   end
```

i get the following error:
Index exceeds number of subplots.
Any thoughts?

Comment: by `8x8` blocks do you mean `8x8` pixels or divide an image into `8x8` grid?

Comment: i mean 8x8 blocks of pixels

Comment: I am sorry, so each block has `64 (=8x8)` pixels?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - Yes.  The OP wants to decompose the image into non-overlapping 8 x 8 pixel blocks, and show each pixel block in a figure.  I just wish the OP could communicate better.

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah. 8 x 8 pixel blocks is much clear than 8x8 blocks of pixels for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is because you have more image blocks to show than you have subplot spaces when plotting.  Change your `for` loop code to this instead:

```
p = 1;
figure;
for c=1:size(ca,1)
    for r=1:size(ca,2)
       subplot(size(ca,1),size(ca,2),p); %// Change
       imshow(ca{c,r});
       p=p+1;
    end
end
```

This way, you will have as many subplot spaces to plot as you have pixel blocks to show.

Comment: That's because you need to spawn a new figure.  Try doing `figure;` before the `for` loop and try again.

Comment: i did 2 figures before the loop and it is still empty

Comment: @RéaH.Rahhal It works for me....  I just tried it with a colour image myself.  I ran your exact code with the modifications I made.  I see an output.  Make sure you load in a **colour image**.  It may also help if you show us what image you're using too.

Comment: @RéaH.Rahhal - Yes, you spawned two figures, but you need to spawn **ANOTHER** one.  Those two figures are for the original image and its YCbCr equivalent.  You need **ANOTHER** one to show the decomposed blocks.

Comment: the original image dimensions are:<1200x1600x3 uint8>.i spawned 3 figures before the loop and i still don't get any result.i chose an image which dimensions are divisible by 8

Comment: @RéaH.Rahhal - no wonder.... you're not getting a result because **it's taking too long**.  Do you realize how many 8 x 8 blocks you're going to generate with that large of an image?  It would also not be recommended you show all of the blocks in a single figure because there would be so many.  I don't know if the MATLAB renderer can handle something like that.  You're getting nothing because MATLAB is **still running in the background** to accomplish what you want.  Try resizing the image so that it's smaller, then try running your code.  You'll get results much faster.

Comment: @matlabuser - Did this code work for you?  Consider accepting my answer if it did.