# how can i apply exact dct2 on 8x8 blocks and display them in subplots?

Tags: matlab

```
I=imread('ft.jpg'); 
 [a b]=size(I);
 figure;imshow(I);
j=rgb2ycbcr(I);
[m n]=size(j);
figure;
imshow(j);
ca=mat2cell(j,8*ones(1,size(j,1)/8),8*ones(1,size(j,2)/8),3);
p = 1;
figure;
figure;
X=ones(m,n,8,8);
for c=1:size(ca,1)
    for r=1:size(ca,2)


 temp=zeros(8,8,'uint8');
   temp(:,:)=X(c,r,:,:);
   temp=temp-128;
   temp=dct2(temp);

   subplot(size(ca,1),size(ca,2),temp(:,:)); %// Change
   imshow(ca{c,r});
   p=p+1;
    end
end
```

the error is:
 Error using ==> subplot at 309
Illegal plot number.

Error in ==> project at 22
       subplot(size(ca,1),size(ca,2),temp(:,:)); %// Change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not calling `subplot` properly.  It needs `p` as the parameter for the third argument, not `temp`.  `p` determines which slot you want to place your figure in.  You putting in a `double`vector as the third parameter makes no sense.  Also, `ca` contains 8 x 8 pixel blocks, and you'd like to show the DCT of each block.  Your current code does not do this.  Actually, `X` is what you're trying to find the DCT of, and it's all ones.... doesn't make much sense.

You probably want to show the DCT of each block inside the figure as well, not `ca`.... and so you need to do this:

```
for c=1:size(ca,1)
    for r=1:size(ca,2)

        temp = double(ca{c,r}); %// Change - cast to double for precision
        temp=temp-128;
        temp=dct2(temp);

        subplot(size(ca,1),size(ca,2),p); %// Change
        imshow(temp,[]); %// Change here too
        p=p+1;
     end
end
```

Note that I did `imshow(temp,[]);` so that we can contrast stretch the block so that the minimum value gets mapped to black while the maximum value gets mapped to white.  Everything else is a shade of gray in between.  Be advised that this **doesn't change the image itself**.  It only changes it for display.

## Suggestion

You should read up on my post on how `subplot` works here:  [How does subplot work and what is the difference between subplot(121) and subplot(1,2,1) in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337813/how-does-subplot-work-and-what-is-difference-between-subplot121-and-subplot1/24337903#24337903)

Once you read through this post, you'll have a better understanding of how each parameter works for `subplot`, and how you can display graphs / images in a figure.

## Minor Note

Looks like you took that code [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074716/how-can-i-decompose-an-image-into-8-x-8-pixel-blocks/27074888#27074888) but you didn't copy and paste properly :)  That `%// Change` comment, as well as the variable name `ca` looked oddly familiar.

Comment: but i need to see the dct2 applied on the blocks.how can i do this?

Comment: @matlabuser , if you find the answers (like in the other post) useful for you, don't forget to accept them. Its the small tick next to the number next to the answer itself.

Comment: @matlabuser - You weren't showing the DCT of each block properly.  I've modified my post.

Comment: @matlabuser - Made a small typo in the `for` loops with getting a block.  Please check the new edits.